# No me va el Login form en symfony cuando la contraseña y el usuario es correcta

Tags: php, symfony3

Estoy tratando de crear un login en symfony 3.4 que conecte a una base de datos existente. Cuando fallas el usuario y la contraseña el login sale el mensaje de credenciales incorrectas, pero cuando pongo el usuario correcto y la contraseña mal no sale el mensaje y si pongo ya el usuario correcto y la contraseña correcta tampoco funciona, os dejo aqui mi código a ver que le pasa.

Empezamos por el security.yml

```
security:

     encoders:
            FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
            AppBundle\Entity\Users:
                algorithm: bcrypt
                cost: 4

        providers:
            our_db_provider:
                entity:
                    class: AppBundle:Users
                    property: user

        firewalls:
            dev:
                http_basic: ~
                provider: our_db_provider
                pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false
                user_checker: security.user_checker
                anonymous: ~
                form_login:
                    login_path: login
                    check_path: login

            main:
                provider: our_db_provider
                user_checker: security.user_checker
                anonymous: ~
                form_login:
                    login_path: login
                    check_path: login

        access_control:
            - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Continuamos con la entitidad de usuarios

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Users
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $pass;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $email2;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $tlf;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $movil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $extmovil;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $menu;

    /**
     * @var bool|null
     */
    private $admin;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $primeraVez = '1';

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $changePass;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $idUser;


    /**
     * Set user.
     *
     * @param string $user
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set pass.
     *
     * @param string $pass
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPass($pass)
    {
        $this->pass = $pass;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pass.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPass()
    {
        return $this->pass;
    }

      /**
     * Get password.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->pass;
    }

    /**
     * Set name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set surname.
     *
     * @param string $surname
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get surname.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * Set email.
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set email2.
     *
     * @param string|null $email2
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setEmail2($email2 = null)
    {
        $this->email2 = $email2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email2.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getEmail2()
    {
        return $this->email2;
    }

    /**
     * Set tlf.
     *
     * @param string|null $tlf
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setTlf($tlf = null)
    {
        $this->tlf = $tlf;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tlf.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getTlf()
    {
        return $this->tlf;
    }

    /**
     * Set movil.
     *
     * @param string|null $movil
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setMovil($movil = null)
    {
        $this->movil = $movil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get movil.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getMovil()
    {
        return $this->movil;
    }

    /**
     * Set extmovil.
     *
     * @param string $extmovil
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setExtmovil($extmovil)
    {
        $this->extmovil = $extmovil;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get extmovil.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExtmovil()
    {
        return $this->extmovil;
    }

    /**
     * Set menu.
     *
     * @param string $menu
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setMenu($menu)
    {
        $this->menu = $menu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get menu.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMenu()
    {
        return $this->menu;
    }

    /**
     * Set admin.
     *
     * @param bool|null $admin
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setAdmin($admin = null)
    {
        $this->admin = $admin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get admin.
     *
     * @return bool|null
     */
    public function getAdmin()
    {
        return $this->admin;
    }

    /**
     * Set primeraVez.
     *
     * @param int $primeraVez
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPrimeraVez($primeraVez)
    {
        $this->primeraVez = $primeraVez;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get primeraVez.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getPrimeraVez()
    {
        return $this->primeraVez;
    }

    /**
     * Set changePass.
     *
     * @param \DateTime $changePass
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setChangePass($changePass)
    {
        $this->changePass = $changePass;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get changePass.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getChangePass()
    {
        return $this->changePass;
    }

    /**
     * Get idUser.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdUser()
    {
        return $this->idUser;
    }

//     public function getUsername()
// {
//     return $this->email;
// }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    // public function getRoles()
    // {
    // // En este caso definimos un rol fijo, en el caso de que tengamos un campo role en la tabla de la BBDD    tendríamos que hacer $this->getRole()
    //     return array('ROLE_USER');
    // }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

}
```

Bueno el twig es simplemente el formulario pero si que funciona ya que con in memory en el secure.yml si que ha funcionado hasta ahora que he decidido ponerle la base de datos.

Yo creo que el error tal vez esta en que solo encuentre el usuario pero la contraseña, no sepa a que columna hace falta.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder realzar un login usando un proveedor propio de base de datos (por ejemplo, una tabla Usuario [Users en tu caso]) debe implementar la clase de Symfony `UserInterface`, esta clase agrega algunas funciones que debes definir como el ejemplo que expongo.

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UsuarioRepository")
 *     
 */
class Usuario implements UserInterface
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;


    ###############################################################
    ###################### Custom Functions #######################
    ###############################################################

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return [
            'ROLE_USUARIO', // si tienes una relación con una clase rol, debes retornar por este lugar en formato arra
        ];
    }


    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password; // retorna tu atributo de password
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method. //si usas algún encriptador con salt, va acá
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->correo; // el username que quieres usar
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }

}
```

En [Este enlace](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/entity_provider.html) puedes ver la documentación que necesitas (la parte de los serialize no es estrictamente necesaria). Recuerda que el password del usuario ya debe estar guardado de manera encriptada en la BD para realizar la acción de login.

Answer (score 1):

a mi me pasa casi lo mismo, es lo siguiente:
cuando pongo la contrasenna o el nombre de usuario mal me saca: "credenciales incorrectas", o sea, ahí sí funciona bien, pero al igual q tú, cuando pongo el nombre y la contrasenna correctos me saca igual el mensaje "credenciales incorrectas", y en el security.yml ya puse el provider de la bd y todo lo demas: our_db_provider:, AHI VA EL security.yml COMPLETO:

### security.yml

## To get started with security, check out the documentation:

## http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

security:
encoders:
AppBundle\Entity\Usuario: bcrypt #usando la codificacion bcrypt

```
    #codificacion bcrypt, variante de planteo:
    #AppBundle\Entity\Usuario:
        #algorithm: bcrypt #Variante

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    #in_memory:
        #memory: ~
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:Usuario
            property: username
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
        logout:
            path:   /logout/
            target: /
#access_control:
    #- { path: ^/gestionTapas, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    #- { path: ^/reservas, roles: ROLE_USER }
    #El ROLE_USER (puesto en el lugar de ROLE_ADMIN en el primer path) q me deberia permitir entrar, tambien impide entrar al igual que el ROLE_ADMIN.
    #El 2do path es aumentando la restriccion de los roles

        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
```

En resumen, a mi tampoco me funciona, todo esta bien, pero no se logea

Comment: Hola Ariel, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, 

si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, antes 

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.